# How do I know if p-hat is in the 75th percentile?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a statsmodels GLM model that returns a prediction: p-hat. If p-hat is in the 75th percentile I should assign the observation "class 1". If p-hat is below the 75th percentile I should assign the observation "class 0". **How do I know what percentile p-hat falls in?**

I saved my p-hats as a list in python. Do I simply look at what p-hats are greater than .75?

```
['1' if i > .75 else '0' for i in phat]
```

Comment: Do you mean that you’ve built a logistic regression (or probit) and are getting predicted probabilities that you want to convert to classes, depending on whether or not the predicted probability is greater or less than $0.75?$

Comment: I'm using someone else's logistic regression model--but yes. I'm trying to convert the probabilities to classes. The business has requested that "classify any observation that would fall in the top 5 bins as "class 1"; for simplicity, we will say the cutoff is at the 75th percentile".

Comment: Your list comprehension should do the trick, but how do you get 75th percentile from “top five bins”?

Comment: I think the problem is worded in a confusing way. I'm not sure what the "bins" are either.